# Validating numeric input using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression in Java to validate a number with the following constraints:

1. The number can be of any length but can only contain digits
2. First digit can be 0 - 9
3. Subsequent digits can be 0 - 9, but one of the digits must be non-zero.

For example: `042004359` is valid, but `0000000000` is not.

Comment: Please leave reason for downvote

Comment: Is `0` valid? You say that the number can be any length and the first digit can be 0-9, and apply the restriction that "one of the digits must be non-zero" in the sentence referring to "subsequent digits", but it seems likely you intended that no all-zero number would be valid.

Comment: Per @Keppil's comment on LouisWasserman's answer below, is #3 intended to restrict the subsequent digits to having at least one non-zero digit even if the first digit is non-zero?

Answer (score 3):

`\\d+[1-9]\\d*` should work, I'd think.

Comment: Change the first `*` to a `+`, and you are home.

Comment: I disagree, actually. If I changed the first `*` to a `+`, then this would only accept numbers with at least 2 digits, which I don't think is correct.  (As it stands, the `[1-9]` is mandatory, so that forces at least one digit to be present.)

Comment: According to the specs, one of the numbers after the first one has to be non-zero, but your pattern accepts `10000` for example. This also implies that the number is at least of length 2.

Comment: Hrrrrm.  I read the spec as "one of the digits in the whole string must be nonzero," but I suppose that reading makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
/^(?=.*[1-9])([0-9]+)$/
```

Whilst it matches all of digits **[0-9]** it contains a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure there is at least one of **[1-9]**.

I am fairly certain that Java allows can use lookaheads.

**EDIT**: This [regular expression test page](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) seems to imply that it can.

**EDIT**: If *0* is valid, then you can use this:

```
^((?=.*[1-9])([0-9]+)|0)$
```

This will make an exception for **0** on its own (notice the OR operator).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{1})(\d*?[1-9]{1}\d*)*$
```

^(\d{1}) - Line must start with 1 digit
(\d*?[1-9]{1}\d*)*$ - Line must end with zero or more 0-9 digits(? for conservative), then 1 1-9 digit, then zero or more digits. This pattern can repeat zero or more times.

Works with:

100000
100100
1010200
1
2

Maybe this is too complicated, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using lookarounds: `(?<=\D|^)\d+(?=[1-9])\d*`

```
(?<=\D|^)   # lookbehind for non-digit or beginning of line
\d+         # match any number of digits 0-9
(?=[1-9])   # but lookahead to make sure there is 1-9
\d*         # then match all subsequent digits, once the lookahead is satisfied
```